# Can a bacteriophage be used to treat bacterial diseases?

Tags: bacteriology, pathology, bacteriophage

Some bacteriophages reproduce using the lytic cycle which ends with the destruction of the host bacterial cell. I was wondering if theoretically this could be used therapeutically to treat bacterial diseases.

Comment: Yes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phage_therapy

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this is possible and is researched as an alternative to antibiotics. It has been used experimentally before antibiotics became widely available. Research was abandoned when antibiotics became widely available. See for example [here](http://journals.lww.com/amjmedsci/Citation/1930/03000/THE_USE_OF_BACTERIOPHAGE_FILTRATES_IN_THE.5.aspx) and [here](http://archpedi.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=1176117) for reports on this.

Today bacteriophages are researched for the treatment of bacteria which have a lot of resistances against antibiotics like Mycobacterium tuberculosis, Enterococcus faecalis, Staphylococcus aureus, Acinetobacter baumannii and Pseudomonas aeruginosa. See the references for more details (the first article also contains a nice historic overview of the field):

- [Bacteriophage Therapy](http://aac.asm.org/content/45/3/649.short)
- [Bacteriophages: an appraisal of their role in the treatment of
  bacterial infections](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0924857907002038)
- [New ways to treat bacterial infections](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1359644602024984)